# Changing Label colour through button template C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In an attempt to use a Click event on a label I have found an example of using a button but applying a template to it so that it looks like a label. As shown below:

```
<Button Name="LooksLikeALabel" Canvas.Left="279" Canvas.Top="-37" Height="26" Width="48" Content="Words" Click="answer1Label_MouseUp" MouseEnter="answer1Label_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="answer1Label_MouseLeave">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Label x:Name="buttonLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Now I want to be able to change the colour of the text on mouse over. Changing the foreground on the button does nothing bot in the code behind and through the XAML. Changing the colour of the label foreground works through the XAML but for whatever reason I am unable to access the label through the code behind meaning I can't access any of the label controls through my C#.

Is there something I am missing to get control over the label in the code behind? Alternatively, is there a better way to have a click event on a label?

Answer (score 2):

Put Trigger inside `ControlTemplate` of button:

```
<Button Name="LooksLikeALabel" Canvas.Left="279" Canvas.Top="-37" Height="26"
        Width="48" Content="Words">
   <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Label x:Name="buttonLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter TargetName="buttonLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
           </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: What trigger would I need to use for a mouse click? `Button.IsPressed` seems to be correct. And how would I get that to fire a method in the code behind?

Comment: `Button.IsPressed` will work for that. `Fire a method in code behind?`-  Hook a handler on Click event. Hope thats what you want..!!